# How to block certain HTTP request with mod_rewrite?

Tags: linux, apache, mod-rewrite

The created  RewriteCond regex dont catch the log excerpt, although its tested. Hence the request doesnt get blocked as expected.

I would like to block requests to the below URL

The RewriteCond statements regex was tested against the log excerpt with regex101.com, but doesnt seem to catch the excerpt when applied on the server.

First I tried the whole Request URL, but even (the much shorter) RewriteCond below, dont catched the Request. I also tried

Request that should be blocked:

```
www.foobar.com/?eID=FOO&type=bar&search%5Bthis%5D%5Bthat%5D%5Btest%5D%5Blatitude%5D=11.1111111111111
```

## 1 Rewrite Rule - dont catches the aforementioned URL:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(\/)[?](eID=FOO)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

## 2 Same with this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(\/\?)(eID=FOO)$ [NC]
```

I expected the request to be blocked. But none of the above works.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Best regards,

Marc

Answer (score 0):

Insted of REQUEST_URI try the below mention QUERY_STRING and make sure that rewrite_module is Loaded or Enabled

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(eID=FOO).* [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L] 
</IfModule>
```

LoadModule rewrite_module /opt/jboss/httpd/lib/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so